amscd for beamer to change color for some arrows in the diagram
I wrote this code (I need to use amscd for beamer and it works almost fine)
 \begin{frame}{Stackexchange}
    \begin{align*}
    \begin{CD}
    A @. {\color{lightgray}B}\\
    @VVV @AAA\\
    C @. {\color{lightgray}D}\\
    @VVV @AAA\\ 
    G @>>> H
    \end{CD}
    \end{align*}
    \end{frame}

in a hope to focus the diagram on $A,C,G,H$ not $B,D$ but I also want the arrow between $D,B$ to be lightgray too. How to do that? Thank you.


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

I recommend abandoning amscd and switching to tikz-cd.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{StackExchange}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[d] \& \mathcolor{lightgray}{B} \\
C \arrow[d] \& \mathcolor{lightgray}{D} \arrow[u,color=lightgray] \\
G \arrow[r] \& H \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


The option ampersand replacement=\& is not generally needed (and & can be used for denoting “go to the next cell”), but it is in this case because of how frame works.
